# PHP number format 4 digits

Tags: php, numbers, number-formatting

For example, I have this format:
`$s_number = "12";` And for this input, I need `0012` as the output:

Another example:

Input `$s_number = "3";`
Output: `0003`

Every time I need 4 digits I would like this to happen.

Comment: `printf` can already do this: `printf("%04d", $number)`. There's also `sprintf` if you want the result in a string.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try using something like sprintf (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or just prepending text based on the length of the string?

Answer (score 16):

It won't be a number (but a string), but you can do that using str_pad. In your examples:

```
$s_number = str_pad( "12", 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT );
$s_number = str_pad( "3", 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT );
```

Answer (score 14):

Use [`str_pad()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) for that:

```
echo str_pad($number, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Thank you, also I have succes with this
$p = substr(sprintf('%04d', $digit),0,4);

Comment: Note that str_pad is **much** faster ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this easily by using phps' `printf`

```
<?php
$s_number = '12';
printf("%04d", $s_number);
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: ah thanks. Totally forgot they printf also prints it out (stupid of me cus it is also in the name of the function)